# Apache vhost rewrite goes wrong with existing folders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, vhosts

I want my vhost to rewrite urls such as:
**http://dev.example.com/cool/story/bro**

To:
**http://dev.example.com/index.php?url=cool/story/bro**

Unless specifying an existing file such as:
**http://dev.example.com/images/duck.png**

---

It works fine but when I have a url which uses an existing folder such as:
**http://dev.example.com/images**

It strangely redirects to:
**http://dev.example.com/images/?url=images**

When it should rewrite to:
**http://dev.example.com/index.php?url=images**

---

Here's my current code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName dev.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/dev/public

        php_flag display_errors 1
        php_value error_reporting 30719

        <Directory "/var/www/dev/public">
                RewriteBase /
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've been trying to fix it for hours but I can't see the problem, hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to specify a RewriteCond for paths that are existing directories in addition to ones that are existing files.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: That just makes it show the directory which is not what I wanted. It should rewrite to http://dev.example.com/index.php?url=images like the others.

Comment: Nope, that still redirects to /images/?url=images

EDIT: Yet it still uses /index.php. Maybe it's looping and applying the rewrite twice? Maybe some tips on how to debug this to check?

Comment: Testing on my own servers, the above should work as intended.
I would try removing RewriteBase and specifying a forward-slash before index.php. Or you could try using the fully qualified path "/var/www/dev/public" instead to rule that out.

Comment: I tried both and it still does it. Is there a way to see exactly what Apache does with a request?

Comment: Not exactly, but you can have it log the rewrite actions to a log that you could follow.
RewriteLog "/path/to/file/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteLogLevel

Answer (score 0):

I've come looking for a solution to this same problem, and @Chris Hendry's comment suggesting the rewrite log was very helpful in debugging this.

> Not exactly, but you can have it log the rewrite actions to a log that you could follow. RewriteLog "/path/to/file/rewrite.log" RewriteLogLevel 3 httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteLogLevel – Chris Hendry

I traced the issue to Apache adding a trailing slash automatically whenever a folder is requested without it, as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354238#answer-13354276

Apache sees that a directory has been requested, and causes a 301 redirect to the "Correct" location.

The issue was fixed for me when I added this directive to my .htaccess file (in your case, it should work in the the vhost itself):

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

**Edit:** Make sure to clear your cache before testing again. The 301 redirect is cache.